# Sentence detection in russian

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

I am using Apache OpenNLP library. I am working on a project that needs several NLP tasks performed in different languages and among those Russian is a very important one. However I do not know russian and cannot find any OpenNLP models for russian.

So the only way I can reliably perform sentence detection is to train a sentence detector on a Russian text and produce a model that I will use later. The text I have to analyze is very specific and is not general enough to create a valid model.

Therefore I am asking if anyone can provide me a russian reference text divided in sentences that is general enough (contains common idioms, abbreviations, etc...). I don't know how long it should be since the documentation doesn't specify a suggest size for training texts. However, I think that maybe a few hundred sentences would be enough.

Comment: Is this general enough for you? 
http://www.voppsy.ru/issues/1981/816/816005.htm
Seriously, find a wikipedia article on any topic of interest, click Русский on the left hand side, get as many sentences as you like. 
What does this have to do with java anyway?

Comment: I don't know, but it looks like it may work. I'll have to do some tests

Answer (score 1):

In the end I took the document suggested in the first comment, plus some articles on wikipedia and achieved 98% precisiion, so it's fine :3